# The entity type T requires a primary key to be defined. If you intended to use a keyless entity type call 'HasNoKey()'

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.0

I have just done the upgrade from EF Core 2.2 to EF Core 3.1. After this I am experiencing this error.
I have defined this class:

```
public class AdminCompanies
{
    public int Code { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName{ get; set; }
    public string Owner{ get; set; }
    public short? Administrator{ get; set; }
    public short? Type { get; set; }
}
```

With this configuration:

```
public class AdminCompaniesConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<AdminCompanies>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<AdminCompanies> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("UTENTI");
        builder.Property(t => t.Code).HasColumnName("CODICE");
        builder.Property(t => t.CompanyName).HasColumnName("RAG_SOCIALE").HasMaxLength(80);
        builder.Property(t => t.Owner).HasColumnName("PALLETS");
        builder.Property(t => t.Administrator).HasColumnName("AMMINISTRATORE");
        builder.Property(t => t.Type).HasColumnName("TIPO");
        builder.Property(t => t.Owner).HasMaxLength(1);
        builder.HasKey(t => t.Code);
    }
}
```

Assigned in the "OnModelCreating" of the context:

```
            modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new AdminCompaniesConfiguration());
```

Everything seems fine, but when I try to use the *context.Database.ExecuteSqlRawAsync* I get this error and I can't understand why.
This is the stack trace:

```
Message: 
Assert.Throws() Failure
Expected: typeof(System.Exception)
Actual:   typeof(System.InvalidOperationException): The entity type 'AdminCompanies' requires a primary key to be defined. If you intended to use a keyless entity type call 'HasNoKey()'.
---- System.InvalidOperationException : The entity type 'AdminCompanies' requires a primary key to be defined. If you intended to use a keyless entity type call 'HasNoKey()'.
Stack Trace: 
ModelValidator.ValidateNonNullPrimaryKeys(IModel model, IDiagnosticsLogger logger)
ModelValidator.Validate(IModel model, IDiagnosticsLogger logger)
ValidatingConvention.ProcessModelFinalized(IConventionModelBuilder modelBuilder, IConventionContext context)
ImmediateConventionScope.OnModelFinalized(IConventionModelBuilder modelBuilder)
ConventionDispatcher.OnModelFinalized(IConventionModelBuilder modelBuilder)
Model.FinalizeModel()
ModelBuilder.FinalizeModel()
ModelSource.CreateModel(DbContext context, IConventionSetBuilder conventionSetBuilder)
ModelSource.GetModel(DbContext context, IConventionSetBuilder conventionSetBuilder)
DbContextServices.CreateModel()
DbContextServices.get_Model()
<>c.<TryAddCoreServices>b__7_3(IServiceProvider p)
CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitFactory(FactoryCallSite factoryCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
CallSiteVisitor.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite singletonCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
CallSiteVisitor.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
CallSiteVisitor.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite singletonCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
CallSiteVisitor.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
ServiceProviderEngine.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type serviceType)
ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
DbContext.get_DbContextDependencies()
DbContext.get_InternalServiceProvider()
IServiceProvider>.get_Instance()
InfrastructureExtensions.GetService[TService](IInfrastructure accessor)
AccessorExtensions.GetService[TService](IInfrastructure accessor)
DatabaseFacade.get_Dependencies()
IDatabaseFacadeDependenciesAccessor.get_Dependencies()
RelationalDatabaseFacadeExtensions.GetFacadeDependencies(DatabaseFacade databaseFacade)
RelationalDatabaseFacadeExtensions.ExecuteSqlRawAsync(DatabaseFacade databaseFacade, String sql, IEnumerable parameters, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
AdminUsersRepo.InsertUpdateUserAsync(Int32 senderCompany, Decimal senderId, AdminUsers user, String modalita, Int32 userCompany) line 281
----- Inner Stack Trace -----
ModelValidator.ValidateNonNullPrimaryKeys(IModel model, IDiagnosticsLogger logger)
ModelValidator.Validate(IModel model, IDiagnosticsLogger logger)
ValidatingConvention.ProcessModelFinalized(IConventionModelBuilder modelBuilder, IConventionContext context)
ImmediateConventionScope.OnModelFinalized(IConventionModelBuilder modelBuilder)
ConventionDispatcher.OnModelFinalized(IConventionModelBuilder modelBuilder)
Model.FinalizeModel()
ModelBuilder.FinalizeModel()
ModelSource.CreateModel(DbContext context, IConventionSetBuilder conventionSetBuilder)
ModelSource.GetModel(DbContext context, IConventionSetBuilder conventionSetBuilder)
DbContextServices.CreateModel()
DbContextServices.get_Model()
<>c.<TryAddCoreServices>b__7_3(IServiceProvider p)
CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitFactory(FactoryCallSite factoryCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
CallSiteVisitor.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite singletonCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
CallSiteVisitor.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
CallSiteVisitor.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite singletonCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
CallSiteVisitor.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
ServiceProviderEngine.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type serviceType)
ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
DbContext.get_DbContextDependencies()
DbContext.get_InternalServiceProvider()
IServiceProvider>.get_Instance()
InfrastructureExtensions.GetService[TService](IInfrastructure accessor)
AccessorExtensions.GetService[TService](IInfrastructure accessor)
DatabaseFacade.get_Dependencies()
IDatabaseFacadeDependenciesAccessor.get_Dependencies()
RelationalDatabaseFacadeExtensions.GetFacadeDependencies(DatabaseFacade databaseFacade)
RelationalDatabaseFacadeExtensions.ExecuteSqlRawAsync(DatabaseFacade databaseFacade, String sql, IEnumerable parameters, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
AdminUsersRepo.InsertUpdateUserAsync(Int32 senderCompany, Decimal senderId, AdminUsers user, String modalita, Int32 userCompany) line 281
```

All the code was working before the upgrade.
Does anyone expirienced the same issue?

Any help would be appreciated

EDIT

This exception is thrown only when I use *context.Database.ExecuteSqlRawAsync*, in other functions everything work as expected.

Also I am getting this error only while mocking the call to ExecuteSqlRawAsync. Otherwise when I call it from the WebAPI it works.

Comment: Are you using asp.net core identity? and are you inheriting `AdminCompanies` with any base class?

Comment: No, I am not usign asp.net core identity or inheriting AdminCompanies

Comment: Btw you can use `modelBuilder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());` in ef core 3.0 to configure your model.

Comment: It doesn't work. I always got the same error. What is strange to me is that I don't see any problem with the breaking changes specified by Microsoft, so why am I getting this error?

Comment: I faced similar issues, when i tried to add a constructor with Entity type or if i set the Id field access modifier to private, Example: `int Code {get; private set;}`

Comment: How did you solved it?